# Flutter :- How to keep centre three words vertically in details page? Below i've attached a image for your reference

Tags: flutter, api, text

eg: details about the questions ........................................................... i want to keep three words(text) vertically align in centre. when i try this not able to display three words vertically centre. I've tried with one word work fine but when i try three words not able to display.Below I've attached a image for reference.[I want to display like this image for details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/preOD.png)

### Details page :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:odia_rasiphala/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsPage({Key? key, required this.title, required this.main_img, required this.content}) : super(key: key);
  // Declare a field that holds the strings passed to this class.
  final String title;
  final String main_img;
  final String content;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('ଆଜିର ରାଶିଫଳ'),
            leading: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                main_img,
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
              ),
              new Center(
                child: new Text(title,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17)),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use replace function:

```
String str = "Some useless words";

String newStr = str.replaceAll(' ', '\n'));
```

Comment: No....Above i've attached a image for your reference . Please check....

Comment: Can you replace this example with english words? I can't understand this lang, sorry

Comment: i want to keep three words vertically like for example i have three words Debendra, Francesco,Amit. i want to display Debendra and Francesco and Amit verically

Comment: Please check above attached image i want display like above attached image.

Comment: just add \n in your string:

Debendra\nFrancesco\nAmit

Comment: @  Francesco Bocci I've dynamic data how to keep it in \n please look the details page code...

Comment: check my new answer